# How to connect two monitors

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, linux-mint, amd-radeon

First of all, sorry about my English; I need to improve that.
I am a new user on linux Mint, and a really new user of Linux enviroments (I have used only Ubuntu 11 and 12 before).
I recently bought a new computer and two new LED monitors: Samsung 19".
I connected the first monitor via the VGA connector and the second one via a graphics card-DVI-to-VGA-to-monitor adapter.

I've spent the last week searching for an answer and can not solve the problem.
So I will start with some basic questions:

Is possible to configure two (independent image) monitors on my computer?

I used the `lshw` command to lookup my hardware and this is the output:

```
description: Desktop Computer
product: To be filled by O.E.M. (To be filled by O.E.M.)
vendor: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.
version: To be filled by O.E.M.
serial: To be filled by O.E.M.
width: 64 bits
capabilities: smbios-2.7 dmi-2.7 vsyscall32
configuration: boot=normal chassis=desktop family=To be filled by O.E.M. sku=To be filled by O.E.M. uuid=9402DE03-8004-7205-F406-0C0700080009
 *-core

   description: Motherboard
      product: F2A55M-HD2
      vendor: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.
      physical id: 0
      version: x.x
      serial: To be filled by O.E.M.
      slot: To be filled by O.E.M.
    *-firmware
         description: BIOS
         vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
         physical id: 0
         version: F3
         date: 02/01/2013
         size: 64KiB
         capacity: 4032KiB
         capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi

*-memory
      description: System Memory
      physical id: 23
      slot: System board or motherboard
      size: 4GiB
    *-bank:0
         description: DIMM [empty]
         product: Dimm0_PartNum
         vendor: Dimm0_Manufacturer
         physical id: 0
         serial: Dimm0_SerNum
         slot: Node0_Dimm0
    *-bank:1
         description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 667 MHz (1.5 ns)
         product: 99U5474-026.A
         vendor: Kingston
         physical id: 1
         serial: 7516D4B7
         slot: Node0_Dimm1
         size: 4GiB
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 667MHz (1.5ns)
    *-bank:2
         description: DIMM Synchronous [empty]
         product: Dimm2_PartNum
         vendor: Dimm2_Manufacturer
         physical id: 2
         serial: Dimm2_SerNum
         slot: Node0_Dimm2
    *-bank:3
         description: DIMM Synchronous [empty]
         product: Dimm3_PartNum
         vendor: Dimm3_Manufacturer
         physical id: 3
         serial: Dimm3_SerNum
         slot: Node0_Dimm3
 *-cache:0
      description: L1 cache
      physical id: 2f
      slot: L1 CACHE
      size: 192KiB
      capacity: 192KiB
      clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
      capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
 *-cache:1
      description: L2 cache
      physical id: 30
      slot: L2 CACHE
      size: 4MiB
      capacity: 4MiB
      clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
      capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
 *-cpu
      description: CPU
      product: AMD A8-6600K APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics
      vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD]
      physical id: 35
      bus info: cpu@0
      version: AMD A8-6600K APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics
      slot: P0
      size: 1900MHz
      capacity: 3900MHz
      width: 64 bits
      clock: 100MHz

      capabilities: x86-64 fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc extd_apicid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq monitor ssse3 fma cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt aes xsave avx f16c lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw ibs xop skinit wdt lwp fma4 tce nodeid_msr tbm topoext perfctr_core arat cpb hw_pstate npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save tsc_scale vmcb_clean flushbyasid decodeassists pausefilter pfthreshold bmi1 cpufreq
      configuration: cores=4 enabledcores=4 threads=4
 *-pci:0
      description: Host bridge
      product: Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Root Complex
      vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD]
      physical id: 100
      bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
      version: 00
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 66MHz
    *-generic UNCLAIMED
         description: IOMMU
         product: Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) I/O Memory Management Unit
         vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD]
         physical id: 0.2
         bus info: pci@0000:00:00.2
         version: 00
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: msi ht bus_master cap_list
         configuration: latency=0
    *-display
         description: VGA compatible controller
         product: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI
         vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI
         physical id: 1
         bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
         version: 00
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
         configuration: driver=fglrx_pci latency=0
         resources: irq:44 memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:f000(size=256) memory:fef00000-fef3ffff
    *-multimedia:0
         description: Audio device
         product: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI
         vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI
         physical id: 1.1
         bus info: pci@0000:00:01.1
         version: 00
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm pciexpress msi bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
         resources: irq:43 memory:fef44000-fef47fff
    *-pci:0
         description: PCI bridge
         product: Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Root Port
         vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD]
         physical id: 4
         bus info: pci@0000:00:04.0
         version: 00
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pci pm pciexpress msi ht normal_decode bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=pcieport
         resources: irq:41 ioport:e000(size=4096) ioport:d0000000(size=1048576)
       *-network
            description: Ethernet interface
            product: RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller
            vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
            physical id: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
            logical name: eth0
            version: 06
            serial: 94:de:80:72:f4:0c
            size: 1Gbit/s
            capacity: 1Gbit/s
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
            configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168e-3_0.0.4 03/27/12 ip=10.9.1.153 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
            resources: irq:42 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:d0004000-d0004fff memory:d0000000-d0003fff

    *-storage
         description: SATA controller
         product: Hudson SATA Controller [IDE mode]
         vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD]
         physical id: 11
         bus info: pci@0000:00:11.0
         version: 40
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 66MHz
         capabilities: storage ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=ahci latency=32
         resources: irq:19 ioport:f190(size=8) ioport:f180(size=4) ioport:f170(size=8) ioport:f160(size=4) ioport:f150(size=16) memory:fef4f000-fef4f7ff
    *-usb:0
         description: USB controller
         product: Hudson USB OHCI Controller
         vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD]
         physical id: 12
         bus info: pci@0000:00:12.0
         version: 11
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 66MHz
         capabilities: ohci bus_master
         configuration: driver=ohci_hcd latency=32
         resources: irq:18 memory:fef4e000-fef4efff
    *-usb:1
         description: USB controller
         product: Hudson USB EHCI Controller
         vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD]
         physical id: 12.2
         bus info: pci@0000:00:12.2
         version: 11
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 66MHz
         capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=ehci_hcd latency=32
         resources: irq:17 memory:fef4d000-fef4d0ff
    *-usb:2
         description: USB controller
         product: Hudson USB OHCI Controller
         vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD]
         physical id: 13
         bus info: pci@0000:00:13.0
         version: 11
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 66MHz
         capabilities: ohci bus_master
         configuration: driver=ohci_hcd latency=32
         resources: irq:18 memory:fef4c000-fef4cfff
    *-usb:3
         description: USB controller
         product: Hudson USB EHCI Controller
         vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD]
         physical id: 13.2
         bus info: pci@0000:00:13.2
         version: 11
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 66MHz
         capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=ehci_hcd latency=32
         resources: irq:17 memory:fef4b000-fef4b0ff
    *-serial
         description: SMBus
         product: Hudson SMBus Controller
         vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD]
         physical id: 14
         bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
         version: 14
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 66MHz
         configuration: driver=piix4_smbus latency=0
         resources: irq:0
    *-ide
         description: IDE interface
         product: Hudson IDE Controller
         vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD]
         physical id: 14.1
         bus info: pci@0000:00:14.1
         version: 00
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 66MHz
         capabilities: ide bus_master
         configuration: driver=pata_atiixp latency=32
         resources: irq:17 ioport:1f0(size=8) ioport:3f6 ioport:170(size=8) ioport:376 ioport:f100(size=16)
    *-multimedia:1
         description: Audio device
         product: Hudson Azalia Controller
         vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD]
         physical id: 14.2
         bus info: pci@0000:00:14.2
         version: 01
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=32
         resources: irq:16 memory:fef40000-fef43fff
    *-isa
         description: ISA bridge
         product: Hudson LPC Bridge
         vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD]
         physical id: 14.3
         bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
         version: 11
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 66MHz
         capabilities: isa bus_master
         configuration: latency=0
    *-pci:1
         description: PCI bridge
         product: Hudson PCI Bridge
         vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD]
         physical id: 14.4
         bus info: pci@0000:00:14.4
         version: 40
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 66MHz
         capabilities: pci subtractive_decode bus_master vga_palette
    *-usb:4
         description: USB controller
         product: Hudson USB OHCI Controller
         vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD]
         physical id: 14.5
         bus info: pci@0000:00:14.5
         version: 11
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 66MHz
         capabilities: ohci bus_master
         configuration: driver=ohci_hcd latency=32
         resources: irq:18 memory:fef4a000-fef4afff
    *-usb:5
         description: USB controller
         product: Hudson USB OHCI Controller
         vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD]
         physical id: 16
         bus info: pci@0000:00:16.0
         version: 11
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 66MHz
         capabilities: ohci bus_master
         configuration: driver=ohci_hcd latency=32
         resources: irq:18 memory:fef49000-fef49fff
    *-usb:6
         description: USB controller
         product: Hudson USB EHCI Controller
         vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD]
         physical id: 16.2
         bus info: pci@0000:00:16.2
         version: 11
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 66MHz
         capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=ehci_hcd latency=32
         resources: irq:17 memory:fef48000-fef480ff

*-pci:1
      description: Host bridge
      product: Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 0
      vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD]
      physical id: 101
      bus info: pci@0000:00:18.0
      version: 00
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
 *-pci:2
      description: Host bridge
      product: Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 1
      vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD]
      physical id: 102
      bus info: pci@0000:00:18.1
      version: 00
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
 *-pci:3
      description: Host bridge
      product: Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 2
      vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD]
      physical id: 103
      bus info: pci@0000:00:18.2
      version: 00
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
 *-pci:4
      description: Host bridge
      product: Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 3
      vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD]
      physical id: 104
      bus info: pci@0000:00:18.3
      version: 00
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
      configuration: driver=k10temp
      resources: irq:0
 *-pci:5
      description: Host bridge
      product: Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 4
      vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD]
      physical id: 105
      bus info: pci@0000:00:18.4
      version: 00
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
 *-pci:6
      description: Host bridge
      product: Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 5
      vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD]
      physical id: 106
      bus info: pci@0000:00:18.5
      version: 00
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
 *-scsi:0
      physical id: 1
      logical name: scsi0
      capabilities: emulated
    *-disk
         description: ATA Disk
         product: WDC WD5000AAKX-0
         vendor: Western Digital
         physical id: 0.0.0
         bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
         logical name: /dev/sda
         version: 15.0
         serial: WD-WMC2E4963559
         size: 465GiB (500GB)
         capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
         configuration: ansiversion=5 sectorsize=512 signature=000d4f5d
       *-volume:0
            description: EXT4 volume
            vendor: Linux
            physical id: 1
            bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,1
            logical name: /dev/sda1
            logical name: /
            version: 1.0
            serial: ed3e2718-d795-4d51-a01b-2cd4c68cc743
            size: 462GiB
            capacity: 462GiB
            capabilities: primary bootable journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink extents ext4 ext2 initialized
            configuration: created=2013-08-27 15:03:50 filesystem=ext4 lastmountpoint=/ modified=2013-09-04 13:27:48 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered mounted=2013-09-04 13:27:48 state=mounted

      *-volume:1
            description: Extended partition
            physical id: 2
            bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,2
            logical name: /dev/sda2
            size: 3549MiB
            capacity: 3549MiB
            capabilities: primary extended partitioned partitioned:extended
          *-logicalvolume
               description: Linux swap / Solaris partition
               physical id: 5
               logical name: /dev/sda5
               capacity: 3549MiB
               capabilities: nofs
 *-scsi:1
      physical id: 2
      logical name: scsi1
      capabilities: emulated
    *-cdrom
         description: DVD-RAM writer
         product: DVDRAM GH24NS95
         vendor: HL-DT-ST
         physical id: 0.0.0
         bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
         logical name: /dev/cdrom
         logical name: /dev/cdrw
         logical name: /dev/dvd
         logical name: /dev/dvdrw
         logical name: /dev/sr0
         version: RN01
         capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
         configuration: ansiversion=5 status=nodisc
 *-scsi:2
      physical id: 3
      bus info: usb@2:3
      logical name: scsi2
      capabilities: emulated scsi-host
      configuration: driver=usb-storage
    *-disk
         description: SCSI Disk
         physical id: 0.0.0
         bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0
         logical name: /dev/sdb
         size: 7408MiB (7767MB)
         capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
         configuration: sectorsize=512 signature=0007c369
       *-volume
            description: Windows NTFS volume
            physical id: 1
            bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0,1
            logical name: /dev/sdb1
            logical name: /media/pc3/Windows USB
            version: 3.1
            serial: 0b67-7649
            size: 7407MiB
            capacity: 7407MiB
            capabilities: primary ntfs initialized
            configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2013-07-22 18:12:46 filesystem=ntfs label=Windows USB mount.fstype=fuseblk mount.options=rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096 state=mounted
```

If someone could provide some insight into the configuration option for this within the Linux Mint environment it would be appreciated

Comment: Don't worry to much about English as people from the community will review new posts and correct mistakes as required. Can you provide more information about the environment your using eg. What version on Linux Mint? Also can you advise what troubleshooting you have tried?

Comment: i am using linux mint 14.
I try to install catalyst software center to configure monitors, but second monitor was never detected.

Comment: Also try install Arandr, and second monitor was´n detected.
I read some about DVI to VGA conectors might have some problems and need to convert the signal from digital to analogic. I have a DVI (25 pins) out from video card and a 15 VGA connector on monitor.
If more info is needed i will try give my best, this is impossible to solve at this point for my self.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Most DVI -> VGA connectors just pass though the existing VGA signal from the 'cross' part of a DVI-I or DVI-A plug.  No active conversion is needed.  Now if you have DVI-D then you need an expensive active device.